# ¿Cómo mostrar el valor de un input en un formulario?

Tags: javascript, html, formularios, checkbox, entrada

En un formulario de compra quisiera mostrar los valores del subtotal, iva, tasa postal y total. Gracias al script que utilizo se muestran los valores anteriores, excepto el del IVA. Me gustaría saber como mostrar este valor, según el código.

(Solucionado) El nuevo código quedaría:

```js
function Suma1(isChecked, valor){
if (isChecked) {
    siniva1 = (parseFloat(document.sumar1.totalsiniva1.value) + parseFloat(valor)).toFixed(2);
} else {
    siniva1 = (parseFloat(document.sumar1.totalsiniva1.value) - parseFloat(valor)).toFixed(2);
 
}
    
document.sumar1.totalsiniva1.value = siniva1;
document.sumar1.total1.value = (parseFloat(document.sumar1.totalactual.value) + parseFloat(siniva1 * 1.12)).toFixed(2);

document.sumar1.iva.value = (parseFloat(document.sumar1.total1.value) - parseFloat(document.sumar1.totalsiniva1.value) - parseFloat(document.sumar1.totalactual.value)).toFixed(2);            


}
```

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<form name="sumar1" method="POST" action="">
  <div class="left">
    <label for="cantidad">Cantidad: *</label><br> 1
    <input type="checkbox" value="150.00" id="1" name="1" onClick="Suma1(this.checked,this.value)" /> 2
    <input type="checkbox" value="300.00" id="2" name="2" onClick="Suma1(this.checked,this.value)" /> 3
    <input type="checkbox" value="450.00" id="3" name="3" onClick="Suma1(this.checked,this.value)" />
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <label for="subtotal">Subtotal</label><input type="text" value="0.00" id="totalsiniva1" name="totalsiniva1" disabled /><br>
    <label for="iva">I.V.A 12%</label><input type="text" value="0.00" id="iva" name="iva" disabled /><br>
    <label for="tasa">Tasa postal</label><input type="text" value="50.00" id="totalactual" name="totalactual" disabled /><br>
    <label for="total">Total a pagar</label><input type="text" id="total1" name="total1" value="50.00" disabled />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: ¿Dónde está el problema?

Comment: No acabo de entender qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente. Y tengo una duda... la tasa postal no se incluye para calcular el IVA?

En cualquier caso:
base + ((base * IVA) / 100) = precio de cualquier cosa + su iva correspondiente. Si el IVA siempre es el mismo (veo un 12% en el código), puedes ponerlo tal cual en su celda no? document.sumar1.iva.value ='12'

Comment: @VeraCanet: La tasa postal es un valor fijo y el iva solo se aplica a los productos. Gracias por tu ayuda, he dado con la solución! :)

Answer (score 1):

Lo hice de otra manera. Los precios y el valor postal, los puse dentro de un *array* con *JavaScript*, en vez de tenerlos en el *HTML*.

Los `input` dejaron de tener `id` y pasaron a formar parte de una clase... Hice una función que detecta si están checkeados los productos, recorriendo uno por uno mediante `map`.

Esto significa que cada vez que se hace click en un producto, tiene que sumar todo otra vez, pero tiene la ventaja de que no se le tienen que pasar parámetros a la función, y además a la computadora le toma el mismo tiempo hacer los cálculos.

Para cambiar el valor del `input` del *IVA*, solo era necesario hacer `iva.value=valor`, asignando el subtotal multiplicado, en este caso, por `0.12`, es decir, un %12.

El postal siempre queda en 50, y el total es `1.12` veces el subtotal más el postal.

```js
var valores = [150,300,450]
var postal_valor = 50

function llenar()
{
  var suma = 0
  var i = 0
  Array.map(document.querySelectorAll(".p"),x=>(suma+=x.checked?valores[i]:0,++i))
  subtotal.value=suma
  iva.value=suma*0.12
  postal.value=postal_valor
  total.value=Math.floor(1.12*suma+postal_valor)
}
```

```html
1 <input type="checkbox" class="p" onClick="llenar()" />
2 <input type="checkbox" class="p" onClick="llenar()" />
3 <input type="checkbox" class="p" onClick="llenar()" /><br/>

Subtotal: <input id="subtotal" disabled /><br/>
IVA %12: <input id="iva" disabled /><br>
Tasa postal: <input id="postal" disabled /><br/>
Total a pagar: <input id="total" disabled />
```